# Auto scrolling TextView in Android widget?

Tags: android, android-widget, textview

I have a widget that displays some text from the web. Sometimes this text runs longer then the widgets height causing the text to be cut off. Is there a way so that if the text is to long to fit vertically in the widgets space it will auto scroll to show the entire message?

Thanks

Comment: This link shows you how to do it:-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868748/is-it-possible-for-textview-marquee-in-a-widget-that-extends-appwidgetprovider

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like a [Scroll View](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html)?

Comment: A ScrollView object is not supported by app widgets http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout. Thanks for the suggestion though.