# android widget text view marquee scroll

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, marquee

can a widget have a marquee textview? if so how would i implement it?

i have tried the following:

```
<TextView

        android:id="@+id/followers"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="@string/load"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="24dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true" >
    </TextView>
```

i know this marquee works as i have made this same textview for a normal app activity and the marquee is working. it just isnt working for the widget side.
the size of the text is longer that the width so that should work.

any help as usual would be much appreciated

Comment: I think this link will help you... <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182578/marquee-text-in-android>

Thanks...

Comment: i've tried that. it hasn't worked

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible for TextView Marquee in a Widget that extends AppWidgetProvider: SOLVED](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868748/is-it-possible-for-textview-marquee-in-a-widget-that-extends-appwidgetprovider)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i believe this is already answered on Stackoverflow,do take a look

[Is it possible for TextView Marquee in a Widget that extends AppWidgetProvider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868748/is-it-possible-for-textview-marquee-in-a-widget-that-extends-appwidgetprovider)

Comment: don't know why i didn't find this one when i was searching lol

Comment: a quick question. do you know how to get the marquee to scroll vertically?

Comment: it should have been set as a standard feature.it makes sense to allow it to scroll in both directions (even all 4 from left to right, top to bottom, bottom to top and left to right) the same needs to be done with sliding drawer. why google thought it would be funny not to allow this is just plain wierd

Comment: true man...i have no idea...bro..Have you heard about vertical text spinner?i knows its not what you and i are looking for..but still just go through it wen your free
http://hi-android.info/src/com/android/music/VerticalTextSpinner.java.html

Comment: i will have a look. dont forget to let me know if you have any luck

Comment: you should really flag as duplicate for situations like this ... but you'll know for next time