# Android: Widget Text fit in Widget

Tags: android, android-widget, textview

I have a `4*2 widget` which contains a `textView` which is `Fill_Parent`.
I have the textSize set to `30dp` and works flawless on my `HTC Sensation`.

On galaxy mini the text wont fit and the user cannot read the text because it's just to much text.

So is there any tip or something I can do to adjust `textSize` to make my text fit?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is too long any easy fix would be defining the [ellipse size to marquee](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3aellipsize). Otherwise I would suggest getting the height and width of the TextView at run time, if it is below a certain threshold then set the textSize to a smaller value.

Comment: is that possible with a widget?

Comment: Ha, short term memory loss; run time doesn't really apply. Perhaps you could let the user build the widget themselves and define an appropriate textSize. But that may over-complicate what you want to do.

Comment: Here's a link to [scrolling in a widget](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868748/is-it-possible-for-textview-marquee-in-a-widget-that-extends-appwidgetprovider) if you to go this route.

Comment: Well, user might not understand what prefrences is :)