# Is it possible to call setSelected() on a widget's TextView?

Tags: android, android-widget, textview

I have a `TextView` in my widget's layout, and I [have it set up as a marquee](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7941802/848393). I'm exploring any possible methods of pausing the marquee scrolling on regular intervals.

One way of doing this, at least in a "normal" scenario, is to call `setSelected(false)`, but because I don't readily know how to--or if I even can--get a reference to the `TextView` I'm not sure how this would work.

Is it even possible to call [`TextView.setSelected()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setSelected%28boolean%29) on a `TextView` that is inside a widget's layout? Are there any other ways that I could start/stop the marquee effect of a widget's `TextView`?