# Widget: No exception and widget does not open

Tags: android, android-widget

My widget gives a problem loading the widget and it doesn't work.

This is the output I receive in logcat output but I'm not sure what it means.

```
W/de.vogella.android.widget.example(1613): onUpdate method called
W/AppWidgetHostView(412): updateAppWidget couldn't find any view, using error view
W/AppWidgetHostView(412):   at android.appwidget.AppWidgetHostView.updateAppWidget(AppWidgetHostView.java:394)
W/AppWidgetHostView(412):   at com.android.launcher2.LauncherAppWidgetHostView.updateAppWidget(LauncherAppWidgetHostView.java:54)
W/AppWidgetHostView(412):   at android.appwidget.AppWidgetHost.updateAppWidgetView(AppWidgetHost.java:376)
W/AppWidgetHostView(412):   at android.appwidget.AppWidgetHost$UpdateHandler.handleMessage(AppWidgetHost.java:101)
W/de.vogella.android.widget.example(1664): onUpdate method called
W/de.vogella.android.widget.example(1664): onUpdate method called
W/de.vogella.android.widget.example(1664): onUpdate method called
W/de.vogella.android.widget.example(1705): onUpdate method called
W/de.vogella.android.widget.example(1744): onUpdate method called
W/AppWidgetHostView(412): updateAppWidget couldn't find any view, using error view
W/AppWidgetHostView(412):   at android.appwidget.AppWidgetHostView.updateAppWidget(AppWidgetHostView.java:394)
W/AppWidgetHostView(412):   at com.android.launcher2.LauncherAppWidgetHostView.updateAppWidget(LauncherAppWidgetHostView.java:54)
W/AppWidgetHostView(412):   at android.appwidget.AppWidgetHost.updateAppWidgetView(AppWidgetHost.java:376)
W/AppWidgetHostView(412):   at android.appwidget.AppWidgetHost$UpdateHandler.handleMessage(AppWidgetHost.java:101)
W/de.vogella.android.widget.example(1744): onUpdate method called
W/AppWidgetHostView(412): updateAppWidget couldn't find any view, using error view
W/AppWidgetHostView(412):   at android.appwidget.AppWidgetHostView.updateAppWidget(AppWidgetHostView.java:394)
W/AppWidgetHostView(412):   at com.android.launcher2.LauncherAppWidgetHostView.updateAppWidget(LauncherAppWidgetHostView.java:54)
W/AppWidgetHostView(412):   at android.appwidget.AppWidgetHost.updateAppWidgetView(AppWidgetHost.java:376)
W/AppWidgetHostView(412):   at android.appwidget.AppWidgetHost$UpdateHandler.handleMessage(AppWidgetHost.java:101)
```

`OnUpdate()` method is triggered using the services. I have posted the service content below:

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
      int[] appWidgetIds) {

    Log.w(LOG, "onUpdate method called");
    // Get all ids
    ComponentName thisWidget = new ComponentName(context,
        MyWidgetProvider.class);
    int[] allWidgetIds = appWidgetManager.getAppWidgetIds(thisWidget);

    // Build the intent to call the service
    Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(),
        UpdateWidgetService.class);
    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, allWidgetIds);

    // Update the widgets via the service
    context.startService(intent);
  }
```

I think the problem is from the layout. If I want to change it to be marquee text, then i get this problem. The layout is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dip"
    android:background="@drawable/myshape" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/update"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="Loading... More text to see if it spans or not and want more" >

        <requestFocus
            android:duplicateParentState="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
    </TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

What does the error message mean and why isn't my widget loading?

Comment: any source code ? onUpdate method can be a clue.

Comment: @StarsSky Please check now. As I said, the problem was after i modified the textview to make it marquee-able.

Comment: give a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/3333855/2015318 maybe you casn solve your problem

Comment: @StarsSky I followd (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868748/is-it-possible-for-textview-marquee-in-a-widget-that-extends-appwidgetprovider) since this is a widget. And the previous link's solution was not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might be useful for others.

Usually, to let the marquee run, in an activity, we set `TextView.setSelected(true)`. In widgets, that should be done inside the xml file, using the tag `requestfocus`. Just in case, i have posted the working xml file.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/update"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:freezesText="true"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    android:paddingLeft="15dip"
    android:paddingRight="15dip"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:singleLine="true" >

    <requestFocus
        android:duplicateParentState="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true" />
</TextView>
```

Cheers.