# How can I scroll all textviews in android widget?

Tags: java, android, xml, widget

I made widget with two **textviews**, only one `TextView` was scrolling... How can I

scroll all **textviews**?

I use this solution from another question but it only work on one `TextView`..

LINK :[Is it possible for TextView Marquee in a Widget that extends AppWidgetProvider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868748/is-it-possible-for-textview-marquee-in-a-widget-that-extends-appwidgetprovider)

```
 <TextView android:id="@+id/fact" android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:text="Loading... More text to see if it spans or not and want more"
            android:singleLine="true" 
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit ="marquee_forever"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:duplicateParentState="true">
        <requestFocus android:focusable="true" android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:duplicateParentState="true" />
    </TextView>
```

How can I scroll all **textviews**?  thanks

Answer (score 0):

Scroll those all the containts within the scroll view

manifest.xml

```
<application>    
<activity
            android:name=".ui.activity.ApsessionMainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
</application>
```

activity.xml

```
    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:isScrollContainer="true"
        tools:context=".ui.activity.ApsessionMainActivity">

    // All other tag


    </ScrollView >
```